# Using a global event bus in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, model-view-controller, flex3

I am using modules in flex , to build different parts of my webapp.
What I need now, is a way these modules can communicate with each other on events.

What really is happening is ,that there is a central module, which then will take care of loading other modules and passing data to and fro.
But , coding for each part to delegate events to each of these loaded modules from the central module and back would be  a big nightmare.

What I really want to do is have a global event bus for it.
Are there any specific libraries , already existing for such a process.
Also, I would be using MVC , so it should also take care between events form the model to the view and vice-a-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about MateMVC.

http://mate.asfusion.com/

This is the exact thing you would need to do to get a global event bus.

Answer (score 1):

Well, about every framework out there can handle it as of today.

We use Parsley + Cairngorm 3 Module library but you could do the same with Swiz, Mate, Spring Flex, Tide or even Robotlegs (and probably others I don't know about)

I would stay away from Cairngorm 2 or PureMVC though because the former doesn't handle well Modules, is bad documented and mostly rely on singletons. And I don't like the Pipe system used in the latter to communicate between modules.

Which one you should use is a bit difficult to say given the few info you gave. It depends if you prefer using Presentation Model over Supervising Pattern, how much you want the framework to be configurable and extensible, if ti should handle both flash and flex, etc...

Comment: Pipes aren't needed with PureMVC unless you are doing multicore and need communication between cores.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the AS3Commons EventBus: http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-eventbus/introduction.html